# How to successfully run elm-coverage?

Tags: continuous-integration, code-coverage, elm

I try to configure `elm-coverage` to be used in CI.

Installation was successful, installed using `yarn` as `"elm-coverage": "0.2.0"`

Our most recent command for running tests is

```
./node_modules/.bin/elm-test --compiler ./node_modules/.bin/elm app/frontend/elm/tests/
```

`app/frontend/` is there, because elm app is within repository of rails app.

When I try to use coverage

```
elm-coverage --elm-test ./node_modules/.bin/elm-test -- --compiler ./node_modules/.bin/elm app/frontend/elm/tests/
```

in (ruby app's) root, it returns

```
MacBook-Pro-6:enectiva admin$ elm-coverage --elm-test ./node_modules/.bin/elm-test -- --compiler ./node_modules/.bin/elm app/frontend/elm/tests/
/Users/admin/git.enectiva.cz/enectiva/node_modules/elm-coverage/node_modules/find/index.js:33
      throw err;
      ^

Error:  does not exist.
    at Object.notExist (/Users/admin/git.enectiva.cz/enectiva/node_modules/elm-coverage/node_modules/find/index.js:41:12)
    at traverseAsync (/Users/admin/git.enectiva.cz/enectiva/node_modules/elm-coverage/node_modules/find/index.js:163:28)
    at /Users/admin/git.enectiva.cz/enectiva/node_modules/elm-coverage/node_modules/find/index.js:282:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Otherwise, I tried

```
MacBook-Pro-6:enectiva admin$ elm-coverage app/frontend/elm/tests/ --elm-test ./node_modules/.bin/elm-test
[12:57:01.68] Instrumenting sources...
[12:57:01.89] Something went wrong:
```

I searched through issues in [Github repository](https://github.com/zwilias/elm-coverage/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue), it does not seem to be reported bug, so there must be something I missed.

Does anyone know, how to actually use it?

Comment: Have you tried running it on your `src` folder rather than your `tests` folder?

Comment: There is actually nothing like `src/`, but `MacBook-Pro-6:enectiva admin$ elm-coverage --elm-test ./node_modules/.bin/elm-test --  app/frontend/elm/
[09:14:54.11] Instrumenting sources...
[09:14:56.08] Something went wrong: 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'tests/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've had a bit more of a play with `elm-coverage`, as I've been able to get it to run on an Elm project of mine.

Firstly `elm-coverage` has a `--verbose` flag which adds extra logging, so try running with that.

I've had best results if I `cd` to the folder containing my `elm.json` file and run `elm-coverage` from there.  In your case, this would look something like the following:

```
cd app/frontend/elm && elm-coverage [source folder] --elm-test ../../../node_modules/.bin/elm-test
```

`[source folder]` is the name of the folder containing your source files (not the `tests`).  For me, `[source folder]` is `src`, but because that's the default I can omit it.